# Where does the value that umask is applied to come from

Tags: umask

I'm trying to understand umask properly.

If I set umask to 0000 and then create a file I get the following permissions:

-rw-rw-rw-

I presume that this value (or set of permissions) is what the umask mask is applied to.

What decides what this unmasked or raw value is? In other words: what value is the umask applied to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Duplicate" of [Where do default file permissions before umask come from?](http://superuser.com/q/476473/150988) (on Super User).

Comment: You are right this does look like a duplicate and I didn't manage to find the other question before asking this. However the answer provided is not as good as the answer provided here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started - from the **OPEN(2)** man page (`man -S2 open`) :

> ```
>    O_CREAT
>           If  the file does not exist it will be created.  The owner (user
>           ID) of the file is set to the effective user ID of the  process.
>           The  group  ownership  (group ID) is set either to the effective
>           group ID of the process or to the group ID of the parent  direc‐
>           tory  (depending  on  filesystem type and mount options, and the
>           mode of the parent directory, see the  mount  options  bsdgroups
>           and sysvgroups described in mount(8)).
>
>           mode specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is cre‐
>           ated.  This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT is  specified
>           in  flags;  if  O_CREAT  is not specified, then mode is ignored.
>           The effective permissions are modified by the process's umask in
>           the   usual  way:  The  permissions  of  the  created  file  are
>           (mode & ~umask).  Note that this mode  applies  only  to  future
>           accesses of the newly created file; the open() call that creates
>           a read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.
> ```

If you `strace` a `touch` command to create a new file, you'll see the mode passed to `open()` is 0666 (i.e. `-rw-rw-rw-`).  The umask mask will be applied to that mode.

```
$ strace -e open touch my-new-file
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("my-new-file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++
$
```